# Knockout JS - one way binding in order to keep server values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm currently setting up a form in Knockout within an MVC application and displaying data from a database, such as:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressPostcode) // This is filled in from the Controller.
```

This is fine, as expected. However, I've worked a lot with Knockout JS and want this value to be used within a search of mine (and thus, `data-bind="value: postcode"` on this postcode element.

The problem? Well, when you bind to `postcode: ko.observable('')`, the pre-populated server value gets replaced with '' (as you'd expect really). Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value binding is overriding the predefined value, I think its a antipattern to use both  server side MVC and client side MVVM, but if you really want to take this route you need to create your own binding like

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueWithInit = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        var value = element.value;

        observable(value);   

        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    },
    update: ko.bindingHandlers.value.update
};
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for this :) I believe it is an "anti-pattern" and sort of contradicts the use of MVVM, but I'm  using it for a business function, rather than a data function.

Comment: Note that this binding requires the use of a observable, you can rewrite it to use the writeValueToProperty function in KO, this function is internal (I did a pull req at Github to get it exported but they havent pulled it yet) so you need to copy it to your binding. WHen using this function the target member on view model does not need to be a observable